# Calculating the minimum in geometry

Tags: geometry

For an app I'm developing I'm faced with a geometry problem and it's a long time since I was doing geometry in school.

[image]

I know the coordinates of A, B and W.I know the length of A-to-Q + Q-to-B I want to know whether there's a Q that has less then x distance from W.

[image]

In this diagram I basically care about the maximum of z. Given that I know the coordinates of A and B I can easily calculate a. b+c is as I said known and we will call it b+c=y.

This basically gives us the following formula (with a and y as known values):
a²=b²+c²
b²=m²+z²
c²=n²+z²
a =m+n
y =b+c

How do I turn that knowledge into knowing the maximum of z?

Comment: If you know the distance from A to Q and the distance from B to Q, then there are only two possibilities for Q, at most.  They're the intersections of the circle of radius $d(A,Q)$ centered at A, and the circle of of radius $d(B,Q)$ centered at B.  Just compute these two points and see if either one meets your requirement.

Comment: With $b+c=y$, point $Q$ lies on an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) with foci $A$ and $B$ and "major diameter" $y$. Since $a^2=b^2+c^2$, there's a right angle at $Q$; by [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), $Q$ lies on a circle with diameter $\overline{AB}$. The circle and ellipse meet at the corners of a rectangle with $\overline{AB}$ as a line of symmetry. All four points yield the same distance $z$, so there's no "maximizing" to be done. The point $W$ doesn't enter consideration. ... Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your intent.

Comment: @saulspatz I don't know the distance from A to Q or B to Q but I know the sum of both. And which I call y later.

Comment: If you are looking for the maximum distance from the line $AB$ it is $z_\text{max}=\frac12\sqrt{y^2-a^2}$.

Comment: My reading of your initial description was something like: *"If $b+c=y$, then does $Q$ get within distance $x$ of $W$?"* (No assumption of a right angle at $Q$.) We still have $Q$ on an ellipse, and we can draw a radius-$x$ circle about $W$; if the curves meet, then $Q$ *does* get within $x$ of $W$. Or we can ask more-specifically for the point $Q$ that's *closest* to $W$.

Comment: @user: Yes, that looks like what I'm looking for. Can you post an answer about why that's the correct formula? (I'm okay with refering to some tool doing the equation solving)

Comment: Here are the steps I think: Find the equation of ellipse with points $A$ and $B$ being the foci and $Q$ a variable point on the circumference of the ellipse. You can do that because you know sum of distance from foci to point on ellipse and you know coordinates of foci. Now that you have the equation of ellipse, find the shortest distance of a point on ellipse from point $W$ - this can be done without calculus. That is the point $Q$ you want.

Comment: I think where made things confusing is when you said maximum $z$. You can simply say point $Q$ which is closest to $W$ if that is what you want.

Comment: @MathLover the thing I actually care about is z. I don't want to calculate Q.

Comment: Is your objective minimizing the distance between $W$ and $Q$ or not? If not, I do not see any relevance of $W$ here.

Comment: @MathLover I want to know the minimum distance to W that's possible.

Comment: Yes so once you find that point $Q$ which has min distance to $W$, you can also find $z$.

Comment: The crucial question: what extreme value you are looking for: the distance from the point $Q$ to the line $AB$ or the distance  from $Q$ to $W$. Generally the position of the point $Q$ will be different for these two cases (unless $W$ lies at the perpendicular bisector of $AB$).

Comment: @Christian: To be clear ... You are *not* assuming a right angle at $Q$, correct? If a right angle is not assumed, then the $a^2=b^2+c^2$ relation should be removed. (The $m$ and $n$ values and relations aren't really needed, either.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok if i understand correctly you need $Q$  with maximal height, this is an isoperimetric problem with fix $y=b+c$ then $Q$ must be on the perpendicular bissector of $[AB]$ and thus $QA=QB=y/2$.

The question may be different since he want the closest point $Q$ to $W$ with $QA+QB=y$ fixed which is quite different...